# Is there any way to edit/modify shop's email templates via the Shopify App api?

Tags: api, email, shopify

I'd like to modify (a.k.a add some text/html) to the shop's email template when the shop installs an application.

They say the apis allow you to change almost anything the shop admin can, but I guess not this one.

Answer (score 2):

Correct, this is not one of the resources that you can access via the API.